Choose between HttpGet and HttpPost when input is complex in .NET core
In .net core web API,
Endpoint: http://localhost:4200/api/GetUsersByName
Input: {"name":"test", "pageSize":10, "pageNo": 1}
The API searches all users which contains name as test and pageSize(total no of records). It is used to get data and input data is complex. So in this scenario which will be better http method HttpGet or HttpPost

Since your input data is a complex format which contains the name, pazesize, page using the post is better than the get method.
By using the post method, the input data could be the formdata and json data format and stored inside the request body which is not visible in the URL or browser history. This helps prevent sensitive data from being exposed in logs or cached by intermediaries.
The GET requests have limitations on the length of the URL and the amount of data that can be sent in the query string.
